# scala pattern matching on functions

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am looking for a way to do pattern matching based on the result of a function evaluation rather than the type of the val. For example,

```
def f1(x:String):Boolean = if (x contains ("Helllo")) true else false
val caller="Hello"

caller match 
{
  case f1(caller) => println ("caller said hello")
  case _ => println ("caller did not say hello")
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: It sounds like you basically want the equivalent of Haskell's [`ViewPatterns`](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) extension.

Comment: I get what u mean, but if it is only strings then u cna probably use regex for pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use pattern guards:

```
caller match 
{
  case x if f1(x) => println ("caller said hello")
  case _ => println ("caller did not say hello")
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @wingedsubmariner did not even know that pattern guards existed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do it without guard, that would a bit faster and cleaner:

```
f1(caller) match {
  case true => ....
  case false => ....
}
```

but for `Boolean` better to use if/else expression, that would be cleaner in byte code and a bit faster

Comment: The advantage of guards afaik is they need not be applied to all cases at once.